# Singleton Pattern "Access to Constructor not Allowed"

Tags: java, android, service, constructor, singleton

I am relatively new to Java, and self-taught, so I expect there will be some fundamental understanding that I am missing.

Background: I am working with Bluetooth which I want to be in a Service, so that I can broadcast received information to multiple activities. This works fine for my MainActivity, but not for any others. Any time a Bluetooth characteristic is read from the device for any other Activity, it fails to read and crashes the program. I discovered that the characteristic is non-null before broadcasting but is null whenever it is received. I believe this is due to mistakenly creating two instances of the service and reading from an instance that is never dealt with. So, to eliminate this possibility, I want to create my Service as a Singleton. (I want to keep the question on-topic so won't ask, but suggestions are appreciated.)

So, I need a single instance of a Service (BluetoothService) which I am using to run and handle some Bluetooth operations. I came across the Singleton design pattern which seems like what I would be after. I implemented it in the way it is described by various sources online:

```
    private static BluetoothService serviceInstance;
    private BluetoothService() {} // Error occurs here

    public static BluetoothService getSharedBluetoothService() {
        if(serviceInstance == null)
            serviceInstance = new BluetoothService();
        return serviceInstance;
    }
```

When an Activity tries to bind to the service, I have the binder class defined as so, in the Activity:

```
public class BtBinder extends Binder {
    BluetoothService getService() {
        return getSharedBluetoothService(); // returns reference to current service
        //return BluetoothService.this; // Line used prior to introducing a Singleton pattern.
    }
}
```

If I understand the error correctly, the private constructor is causing errors with my MainActivity - it cannot instantiate the Service because its constructor is private. If the constructor is made public, MainActivity fails to bind to a Service. onBind() is never call which causes a Null Pointer Exception elsewhere.

Where am I going wrong here? As far as I can see I have followed the correct procedure. I am not sure where to turn.

EDIT:
Binder:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Currently binding");
    BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = manager.getAdapter();   
    return myBinder; // When bound, return the whole MyLocalBinder Binder.
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    // ...
    BluetoothService BtService;
    boolean isBound = false;

    BluetoothBroadcast btSetupReceiver = null;
    BluetoothBroadcast resultsReceiver = null;
    boolean receiversAreRegistered = false;

        private static final String TAG = "BluetoothGattActivity";
        private static final String DEVICE_NAME = "Suspensionometer 3333";

        private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
        private SparseArray<BluetoothDevice> mDevices;

        private BluetoothGatt mConnectedGatt;

        private ProgressDialog mProgress;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Bind the service
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to bind to service.");
            bindService(intent, btServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

            // Set up BroadcastReceiver
            btSetupReceiver = new BluetoothBroadcast(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
            {               
                // ...
        };

        resultsReceiver = new BluetoothBroadcast() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                // ...
        };
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for Binder class ?

Comment: 1. Can you post MainActivity code so we can see where the error happens? 2. Although I don't know enough, I don't think you should have to make an Android service a singleton. I would research a little more before you go in too deep ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not allowed to call my own methods ("static" mystery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684063/not-allowed-to-call-my-own-methods-static-mystery)

Comment: I've added the Binder and MainActivity. Let me know if it's not quite what you were after. In addition to what hatcyl said, I'm sure there are probably other ways to do this and a Singleton is unnecessary. However the idea seemed simple enough to implement at the time and I think I got carried away...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make your Service constructor private. Android needs to be able to create many of its components in response to events that happen on the device. For example, Android could create an instance of your Service class in response to an intent.

What you can do is set up a separate singleton object to do your work, and fetch that object in your Service. However, be careful about the lifecycle of a service. If your service is started in response to an intent or a startService call, then how long that service runs depends on the return value from onStartCommand (START_STICKY etc). The doc gives a good overview:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

EDIT:

It sounds like you mainly just need a common place to store your service's data, and then whatever instance of your service that Android creates can go get that data when one of the activities binds to the service and requests it. It looks like you are using the "LocalService" pattern that is in the docs, which sounds like the right thing to do.

I don't know how complex your bluetooth data is, but the most common ways to store data in Android are SharedPreferences (for simpler key/value data) and databases. If you think can get away with SharedPreferences, then you can use JSON to store a fair amount of complexity as a long string.

If your data is too complex, or is more table-based, then Android comes with SQLiteDatabase and related classes, and also a ContentProvider class which provides URI-type access to the database.

Am I going in the right direction here? I'll stop now, but let me know if you need more explanation, or if I've gone off the rails.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This seems pretty sensible. It would explain why online examples use private - because they aren't referring to Singleton services. Just to check that I am understanding this correctly (since I'm still getting my head around object-oriented code) you're suggesting I create a class to act as the Singleton, and then use that to communicate between the Service class and Activities?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been asleep / looking into SharedPreferences and JSON. LocalService is what I'm doing and I have pretty simple data and SharedPreferences may be useful in for this project. For a better context, what you've said is close to what I want to do. The service is there to store data and to set up and run Bluetooth operations. The Service sends information, upon event triggers, to the Activities which handle the data and update their UI display. Anyway I suppose if I don't use a Singleton it comes back to ensuring I obtain the correct reference to the Service.

Comment: Perhaps I should have worded my above "Singleton" question as something more open for discussion, I think it's what I needed more than anything. I know this will sound silly, but do you have any advice for how to obtain the Service reference instantiated in another activity, which I can then bind to? I tried making the Service instance public but didn't work out.

Comment: I really think you need to move past thinking of your Service as a singleton object -- it's not how Android is designed to work. Think of your Service as a chunk of code that knows how to gather bluetooth data, store it in SharedPrefs, and send broadcasts that your activities can receive, so they can go fetch the data. But you shouldn't keep non-static state in your service (that's only in SharedPrefs), and so it doesn't matter what instance of Service the activity is bound to.

Comment: Alright, thanks. You've given me some ideas to go on, and hopefully after some redesigning of my code structure, it should come together. I'll mark this as the accepted answer because I think it's correct and technically answers the question of "Why doesn't the constructor work?" though the problem isn't technically fixed just yet. I appreciate your taking the time to help me through this!

Comment: Glad to help. If you run into another issue, post another question. My favorite tag is android-fragments :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the offending private to protected and it should do the trick.

Read up on Singletons at this great blog: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. I am currently reading through the link though, just to make sure my knowledge of Singletons matches what is said.